# Postgresql check if string contains many letters

Tags: sql, postgresql

So right now i have a column in my table of School classes called days which contains the days that specific section will run on, like 'TR' would be that it runs on Tuesday and Thursday, and 'MWF' will be it runs on Monday, Wednesday, and Friday.

i want the user to be able to filter by days it runs, so if a class runs 3 times,
MT,MW,TF i want the user to be able to enter MTW, and get the first 2. But the only way i could figure out how to query it correctly, is to make the input string to an array of all possibilities so MTW would become M,T,W,MT,MW,TW,MWT and just see if days is in that array. it works but i am wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: is normalizing/changing the db structure a possibility?

Comment: Yes, it is still heavily in development. what would you suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend creating another table, `class_days`, which contains each day a class will run.

So `MWT` stored in `days` would instead be stored as 3 rows in a separate table

```
class_days
class_id, day
1,M
1,W
1,T
```

Then you can use `not exists` to select classes that do *not* have classes scheduled on a day not given by a user (therefore all classes are scheduled by the given days)

```
select c.id from classes c
where not exists (
  select 1 from class_days cd
  where cd.class_id = c.id
  and cd.day not in ('M','W','T')
)
```

The query above assumes that every row in `classes` has at least 1 corresponding row in `class_days`. If that's not the case, then add an `exists` condition to ensure you're not returning classes that do not have any days setup.

```
select c.id from classes c
where not exists (
  select 1 from class_days cd
  where cd.class_id = c.id
  and cd.day not in ('M','W','T')
) and exists (
  select 1 from class_days cd
  where cd.class_id = c.id
)
```

These queries can take advantage of a composite index on `class_days(class_id,day)`

Comment: Hmm i was trying to avoid having another table. How do you think the speed will compare to this vs the way i am doing it now? since now i will have another table with more than twice the rows as my class table

Comment: @TomerShemesh with a composite index on `class_id`,`day` the additional table should run much faster than what you have for the query of retrieving all classes that are given on a specific set of days

Comment: Ok. would it be bad practice to also have my days column still in classes so that when i am just looking up classes by name, i wont need to do a join to know what the days are?

Comment: @TomerShemesh it depends. if you're doing it for performance reasons then it's a valid to store data to avoid a lookup - but this only applies to very large systems - in your case I would advise against storing the days separately to avoid a join because then you have to maintain 2 sets of code for creating/updating/deleting days

Comment: The table only has 15,000 rows so i assume that its small enough where it would be better to not have the column

Comment: @TomerShemesh yes, at 15,000 rows you will not see any noticeable performance gain from avoiding a query

Answer (score 0):

You need three tables

- Classes 
  ClassID **Primary Key**
- Days 
  DayID **Primary Key**
- ClassDay
  ClassID **Foreing Key** 
  DayID **Foreing Key**

**UPDATE**

Or you could use bitwise operator

Lets say Monday =1, Tuesday = 2, Wensday = 4, Thursday = 8, Friday = 16

In case user want MTW.

You update class

```
UPDATE Class
SET DAY = 1 + 2 + 4
```

and search

```
SELECT *
FROM Class 
WHERE 
     DAY & 1 
AND  DAY & 2
ADN  DAY & 4
```

Comment: @TomerShemesh I think the third table is the way to go, but I add the bitwise solution for your consideration.

Comment: i dont see why i need 3 tables when i think i would only need two as seen above

Comment: Yes, you may skip DAYS table for your case. I just give you the general normalized table. But is the same answer as Fuzzy. Or you create a field to store days with bitwise operator and only need one table.